# Fillable line above the date

Tags: line, date, fill

I'm trying to create a fillable line in a document. I only have this so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\begin{tabbing}
xxxx: \= \kill
Lima, \> \TextField[name=name0,width=5.1cm,charsize=11pt]
{\mbox{}}\\
\end{tabbing}
\vspace{0.6cm}
\begin{tabbing}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: \= \kill
Firma del titular de la entidad y sello \> \TextField[name=name1,width=8cm,charsize=11pt]
{\mbox{}} \\
\end{tabbing}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

But I need the line to be above the date having a format such as:

```
____________,______del________del________
(City)        (day)    (month)    (year)
```

How can I do this? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to  TeX SX! You can define a command, like this: `\newcommand{\filline}[1]{\rule[-0.5ex]{#1}{0.4pt}}`, where the argument is the length you want for your line

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.